# How to deploy js in production?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, generalization

I am React js beginner so I wanted to clarify some things.

Q1. The only way to use React in production is to use webpack-dev-serve ?

Q2. In case that you use webpack-dev-server I should create multiple API which will handle multiple functionalities as another service or microservice ?

Q3. Should you learn node js for further development ? Or it's enough to have knowledge in webpack ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. No! Webpack's dev server is just that--a *development* server that allows you to get features such as hot reloading to better your DX. When you deploy to production, you build your code into a client side bundle with Webpack (literally what Webpack means, **pack**age your code for the **web**). Then serve that bundle and HTML/CSS on your own webserver.

Comment: 3. It depends on what you'll use Node.js for. Node.js was originally meant for server-side JavaScript, but now is used by frontend libraries for its ecosystem and package manager. If you're looking to write server-side apps, Node.js is the runtime to do it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to 1. is no, it's not meant to serve production code.

The answer to 2 and 3: there are many ways to deploy a React app, and the right answer for you is..... it depends. Some of those don't require you to learn node (or anything to set up a server). The React docs actually provide a lot of the ways to start:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

If you have an lightweight page, I would recommend something like Github pages or comparable:
https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

For reference, here's a React project I built for a coding interview:
https://github.com/pink-cupcakes/connect-four

And here is the deployed site via Github pages:
https://pink-cupcakes.github.io/connect-four/

But if you deploy a project with a compiled bundle.js, you can actually just open your index.html and it'll run all of your React goodness. Then your question just becomes - how do you deploy a server, and there are many options for that: Heroku, Azure/AWS.

If that sounds like a headache - take a gander at serverless! (Devops magic - automated)
https://dev.to/adnanrahic/a-crash-course-on-serverless-side-rendering-with-reactjs-nextjs-and-aws-lambda-13ed

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good article describing almost all what you need to know about [Webpack for bundling you React app](https://blog.logrocket.com/versatile-webpack-configurations-for-your-react-application-e6ebf6615cc/).

Since you created the app already, you can scroll down to the required packages installation part in the article.